# How to plot conditionally based on previous plot Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm making simple Swing High and Swing Low finder/alert and everything works grate, except there are a lot of cases that Swing High comes after another Swing high.

Logic is simple - a swing high is defined if two candles before have been lower than this one and two candles after are lower as well

What I want to achieve is to plot swing high only if previous plot has not been swing high.

Here will be the code

```
//@version=4
study("Swing Point Finder")

hhCondition = high[4] < high[2] and high[3] < high[2] and high[1] < high[2] and high < high[2]
llCondition = low[4] > low[2] and low[3] > low[2] and low[1] > low[2] and low > low[2]


plot(hhCondition ? 1 : 0, "Swing High found", color.green, offset = -2)
plot(llCondition ? 1 : 0, "Swing Low found", color.red, offset = -2)
```

Comment: I still have not found a solution for what I'm looking for here, but I found an interesting conditional I can add to this test - I can check is hhCondition highest value in lets say last 10 bars.

`hhCondition = high[4] < high[2] and high[3] < high[2] and high[1] < high[2] and high < high[2] and high[2] > highest(nz(high[3]), 10)`

That eliminates a lot of noise.
Credit goes for this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074111/highest-high-of-the-last-n-days-not-n-days-ago

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that you could try something like this:

```
plot(hhCondition and not hhCondition[1] ? 1 : 0, "Swing High found", color.green, offset = -2)
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but, sorry, no change in result.

By the way is there array formed from plot cases at all?

In documentation I can only find that [x] is only capable to hold a value, but in my case I need to find repeated candle pattern...

Answer (score 0):

yea good catch, I've run into this same issue in multiple scripts I've written.

What'd I would suggest here is creating a variable that tracks all pivot points.

`isPivot == hhCondition or llCondition`

Then, on a new pivot, compare it against the previous one. something like this for example:

```
plotThisHigh = hhCondition
if (hhCondition)
    sameDirection = valuewhen(isPivot, hhCondition, 0)
    plotThisHigh := sameDirection ? false : true
```

duplicate this for checking previous pivot lows as well.
I'd recommend using a different variable for plotting (`plotThisHigh` as opposed to resassigning `hhCondition`) because if there are say three hhConditions in a row (with no llConditions in between) then if you reassign `hhCondition` the logic will no longer work.
does that make sense?

I've written more details in this blog post if you need...hope it helps
https://marketscripters.com/how-to-work-with-pivots-in-pine-script/